# Youtube-dl downloading channel from vimeo

Tags: youtube-dl

Does YouTube-dl allows to download all videos(not individual file) from a channel from sites other than YouTube. (Vimeo, daily motion)

I understand that YouTube-dl can be used to download all videos in YouTube channel/user. 
The syntax is youtube-dl ytuser:fmderena

What are abbreviations for each website. 
For YouTube its ytuser
Similarly is there a code for vimeo

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can look at the [output of `youtube-dl --extractor-descriptions`](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html) to see a list of supported sites (the actual output includes some examples, too). You'll find that vimeo channels are supported. However, you don't even need to consult the list, just try passing in the URL to youtube-dl. Something like

```
youtube-dl http://vimeo.com/channels/YOUR-CHANNEL
```

should just work. If not you can (and should) [file a bug](https://yt-dl.org/bug) to request support. Don't [forget](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#is-the-description-of-the-issue-itself-sufficient) to include the actual example URL you're passing in.

Comment: The url method works. For youtube there's a special syntax "ytuser", but I think for other sites, he full url should be used as phihag suggested.